# Filling an array of strings with the content of a file

Tags: c, arrays, string

I wrote a short code that should copy the content of a file into an initialized array of strings and then print that array. I get no errors/warnings but still the program doesn't print anything when i run it. The code is the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

const int dim = 30;



int main() {

char* arr[dim];
int i = 0;

FILE* fp;
fp = fopen("test.txt", "r+");

if(fp == NULL) {

    printf("\nError, breaking...");
    return 0;
}

while(i <= dim) {

    arr[i] = (char *)malloc(dim*sizeof(char *));
    ++i;

}

i = 0;

while(fscanf(fp, "%s", arr[i]) != EOF) {

    printf("%s: added\n", arr[i]);
    ++i;

}


}
```

The file contains a series of words separated only by whitespaces and newline characters.

Comment: You declare `char *arr[dim]`, but then use `i <= dim`, so you write one past the end of the array (index `dim-1` is the largest legal index).  `(char *)malloc(dim*sizeof(char *))` doesn't make a lot of sense, but should not cause a failure unless you have very long words.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Thanks. Also, when you say that it doesn't make sense to allocate that much space for every string, do you mean that I'm good untill I put a word in the file that is longer than the value of "dim"?

Comment: @wako -- the amount of space you're allocating depends on the size of a pointer on your machine, which is likely not relevant to the length the words expected to be read.  This kind of 'hidden' dependency on the address size is likely to lead you to portability problems later down the road.  Also, casting the return value of malloc is considered bad form.

Answer (score 1):

correct followings and see if it helps

1) initialise i to 0 ie. i=0;

2)

```
while(i < dim) { } // it should be < as array start with 0
```